# Passing string variable into Moment.js subtract function

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am building a website with a dropdown selection and based off the timeframe (day, week, month, quarter, year) the user selects a different result will be displayed.
Instead of writing 5 different functions I would like to write one function that takes the timeframe as a parameter and pass it into the moment().subtract() function. The code is below.

```
let timeFrameString = '"' + timeframe + 's"';
let dateTo = moment().subtract(1, timeFrameString).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

This doesn't work. I have console logged the timeFrameString and it displays exactly as I would type it in if I wasn't using a variable, and I have ran the exact same code just typing in the word 'days' and it works perfectly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a sample on what sort of value the `timeframe` variable would be?

Comment: It will be a string that is either: "day"', "week", "month", "quarter", or "year". I am aware that quarter wont work so there is a different variable for that one.

Comment: The issue is that you are using `"` when creating `timeFrameString`. Supposing that `timeframe` is already a string, you can simply use `let timeFrameString = timeframe + 's';` instead of `let timeFrameString = '"' + timeframe + 's"';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
let timeFrameString = timeframe + 's';

let dateTo = moment().subtract(1, timeFrameString).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to append the double quotes. you can pass the timeframe as param and get the toDate as below for standard time frames. e.g.

```
function getDateForTimeFrame(timeFrame) {
    return  moment().subtract(1, timeFrame).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}

let timeFrame = "month"; // "day", "week"
let dateTo = getDateForTimeFrame(timeFrame );
console.log('dateTo :', dateTo)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Edited
```

as **Nuwan Attanayake** solution worked for you

and you want to `subtract multiple different keys` at the same time, you can pass them in as an object literal like.

```
moment().subtract(7, 'days').subtract(1, 'months'); // with chaining
moment().subtract({days:7,months:1}); // with object literal
```

Comment: Question was answered above, but thank you for the information, I wasn't aware you could pass multiple keys at once.